# Is there a Perl idiom which is the functional equivalent of calling a subroutine from within the substitution operator?

Tags: perl, substitution, subroutine, idiomatic-perl

Perl allows ...

```
$a = "fee";
$result = 1 + f($a) ; # invokes f with the argument $a
```

but disallows, or rather doesn't do what I want ...

```
s/((fee)|(fie)|(foe)|(foo))/f($1)/ ; # does not invoke f with the argument $1
```

The desired-end-result is a way to effect a substitution geared off what the regex matched.

Do I have to write

```
sub lala {
  my $haha = shift;
  return $haha . $haha;
}
my $a = "the giant says foe" ;
$a =~ m/((fee)|(fie)|(foe)|(foo))/;
my $result = lala($1);
$a =~ s/$1/$result/;
print "$a\n";
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpogce). You need to specify the `e` modifier so that the replacement part is evaluated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $x = "the giant says foe" ;
$x =~ s/(f(?:ee|ie|o[eo]))/lala($1)/e;

print "$x\n";

sub lala {
    my ($haha) = @_;
    return "$haha$haha";
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> r
the giant says foefoe
```

Incidentally, avoid using `$a` and `$b` outside of `sort` blocks as they are special package scoped variables special-cased for [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html).

Comment: Thanks!  That saves a lot of wear and tear on the semicolon key.